# Spring Cloud Eureka together with RestEasy

Tags: spring, jersey, resteasy, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

we are evaluating Eureka as central SD environment for our Spring Boot applications. Here we are using Spring Cloud. We figured out, that due to the fact, that we make use of RestEasy quite a lot and Eureka is based on Jersey, we run into bigger conflicts. Our rest-easy based APIs are throwing a lot of errors. It's basically no good idea to mix Jersey with Resteasy in the same application.

Question: Is there a way to change the jersey dependency or remove the lib somehow in order to avoid lib problems with RestEasy?

Best 
fri

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, it's how the eureka client is built.  An alternative might be [spring-cloud-consul](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul), which doesn't use eureka, but provides integration with Ribbon and Zuul. Hystrix also works fine.

Comment: Ah that's not good, I liked the idea of Eureka. Will have a look to spring-cloud-consul then. I guess, there is no way to isolate these two libraries, so they can work along together in one classpath.

Comment: Yeah, it's inherent to Eureka.  I don't know how to get jersey and rest easy to live together.